# Extjs4 how to disable itemClick event of grid's certain column

Tags: grid, extjs4

I am working in extjs4. I have grid panel view as=
[image]

i want to show image in floating window whenever user clicks on grid row.So i have written function namely showImage() and calling it as=

```
me.mon(me, {'itemclick' : me.showImageViewer
        }, me);
```

But i dont want to call this function when user clicks on FileName column of grid. So how to restrict calling showImage function when user clicks on grid column 'FileName'

Answer (score 0):

> i want to show image in floating window whenever user clicks on grid row.

Do you mean you'll show a popup containing the bigger image if image on row is clicked? if yes, on your *showImageViewer* function, you have to check the attributes of the cell if it's an image or you can check its `dataIndex`.

You can also listen to `cellClick` instead of `itemClick`. With that, you can check the `cellIndex` of the cell being clicked. In your case, if `cellIndex` is equal to 2 (index of your FileName column, don't call *showImageViewer*.

```
cellClick : function(view, cell, cellIndex, record, row, rowIndex, e) {

}
```

Comment: thanx for reply sir...But my columns are movable and dreaggable. So may change its ccellIndex. So can i get dataIndex using cellClick

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the column click function. Define common listener for columns you need. In arguments you should recieve grid, cell element, row index, column index, event data and record(in such order). So if you'll move, rename headers or do whatever you want with column with such listener it wouldn't change click listener.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css selector to differentiate between elements inside the row, using a code like the following

```
listeners: {
        itemclick: {
            fn: function (view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                var photo = e.getTarget('.photo');

                if(photo) {
                    alert(record.get('photo'));
                }
            }
        }
```

You can try a [working sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/overlordhammer/SQwZb/12/). Hope it helps to solve your problem